# how to convert Figma screens to flutter dart code?

Tags: flutter, dart, figma

I have screens designed in FIGMA tool, Is there a way to convert screens designed in Figma to flutter?

Comment: You have to hire flutter app developer or try this [FlutterFlow](https://flutterflow.io/) may be helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

There certainly is a way to convert Figma designs to flutter code. You could use the online IDE flutlab.io
Simply go to the page, log in, and import the project from Figma by choosing that option off the toolbar on the right side of the interface. It should take a while to do that conversion, then clicking on build would give you your simulated version of the code.